# Model naming convention in Spine.js and Rails with two words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spine.js

I have a model in rails called WorkRequest and the naming conventions in rails give me the create route of work_requests/ [POST]. In Spine with the same model name it posts to the path workrequests/ Is this by design and do I need to override it somewhere.

Out of interest, what do others use as a naming convention when the model name has more than one word in it? Would it have been better to call the mode Workrequest and have done with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I should have kept looking: http://spinejs.com/docs/ajax. I found that you can override the default path by add @url option to the model.

```
class App.WorkRequest extends Spine.Model
  @configure 'WorkRequest', ... [field list]
  @extend Spine.Model.Ajax
  @url: "/work_requests"
```

I'm still interested in the diference in naming conventions between Spine and Rails with multiword model names.

Comment: Use the JavaScript conventions in the Spine code and the rails conventions in your rails code :) JS classes start with a capital and are in CamelCase. It's just a 'bug' in Spine that it doesn't convert it to proper snake_case for the url but just downcases it all. Perhaps it'll get fixed. For now, your workaround and naming conventions are correct imo.